# MySQLdb doesn't work with utf8mb4

Tags: python, mysql, database, utf8mb4

The commands

```
Import MySQLdb
MySQLdb.connect(user="root", passwd="1234", charset="utf8mb4")
```

Work on Linux. But on Windows it throws the following exception:
`Operational Error (2019, can't initialize character set utf8mb4 (path: c:\\mysql\\\\share\\charsets\\) ")`

That path doesn't even exist on my computer, nor in my code.

I'm using MySQLdb version 1.2.5 and mysql 5.7.18.

Using charset=utf8 is not enough because I need to query something like this \U00023456 (4 bytes unicode code points) .

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Your version of MySQL doesn't support utf8mb4.

Comment: The problem is in the client side and not the server side since MySQLdb is a client side library. Also, 1.2.5 is the newest version of MySQL-python

Answer (score 0):

There are too many backslashes in `c:\\mysql\\\\share\\charsets\\`.  (Before 'share')

Are you using at least mysql 5.5.3?

You probably need `use_unicode=True`, also.

What is in `OPTIONS`?

You mean "4 byte *UTF-8*".

Comment: I know the path has too many backslashes. It only appears in the exception, not in my code. That folder doesn't even exist. I'm using mysql 5.7.18. In addition, adding use_unicode=True didn't solve the problem.  What OPTIONS are you talking about? Thank you.

Comment: The might be an `OPTIONS` in or near the same place where `use_unicode` goes.